# Sending Chunked HTTP request in Java

Tags: java, http, chunked

Trying to use HttpURLConnection to send HTTP chunked POST request.

```
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(16000);
conn.setRequestProperty("format", "InterleavedInt16");
conn.setRequestProperty("number-of-channels", "2");
conn.setRequestProperty("format", "InterleavedInt16");
conn.setRequestProperty("transfer-encoding", "chunked");
conn.setReadTimeout(12000);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setUseCaches(false);
```

have setup the conn as above. My question is do I need to manually breakdown the outputstream as to the chunk size. and call out.write() multiple times for each chunk. Or I can just call out.write() once but pass in the whole stream?

My current code to send the whole stream(assume size is 32000):

```
byte[] data = new byte[32000];
inputStream.read(data);
OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
conn.connect();
out.write(data);
audioStream.close();
out.close();
```

This give me a "unexpected end of stream on Connection" error.

Comment: You only copy a single byte over with this call: out.write(audioStream.read());

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Oh, yes you are right. But, that is not the point. Fixed it.